# BokehUserWarning: ColumnDataSource's columns must be of the same length - Workaround?

Tags: bokeh

I'm trying to create a visualization of a split horizontal bar chart to show differences in distribution by gender (female, male). I created the dataframe manually because it's only 11 rows x 2 columns. When I run the code it shows an empty result and states this warning:

BokehUserWarning: ColumnDataSource's columns must be of the same length. Current lengths: ('+75', 1), ('20-24', 2), ('25-29', 2), ('30-34', 2), ('35-39', 2), ('40-44', 2), ('45-49', 2), ('50-54', 2), ('55-59', 2), ('60-64', 2), ('65-74', 1), ('F', 2)

I checked and the length between female and male are the same, not sure what could be wrong.

```
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.palettes import RdYlBu11
from bokeh.plotting import figure

output_file("example_split.html")

gender = ['F', 'M']
age_group = ["20-24", "25-29", "30-34", "35-39", "40-44", "45-49", "50-54", "55-59", "60-64", "65-74", "+75"]

females = {'F' : gender,
           '20-24'   : [3, 0],
           '25-29'   : [22, 0],
           '30-34'   : [24, 0],
           '35-39'   : [16, 0],
           '40-44'   : [9, 0],
           '45-49'   : [5, 0],
           '50-54'   : [3, 0],
           '55-59'   : [2, 0],
           '60-64'   : [7, 0],
           '65-74'   : [0],
           '+75'     : [2]}
males = {'M' : gender,
           '20-24'   : [0],
           '25-29'   : [0],
           '30-34'   : [9],
           '35-39'   : [20],
           '40-44'   : [22],
           '45-49'   : [16],
           '50-54'   : [11],
           '55-59'   : [6],
           '60-64'   : [7],
           '65-74'   : [0],
           '+75'     : [1]}

p = figure(y_range=gender, plot_height=250, x_range=(-25, 25), title="My_title",
           toolbar_location=None)

p.hbar_stack(age_group, y='gender', height=0.9, color=RdYlBu11, source=ColumnDataSource(females),
             legend_label=["%s females" % x for x in age_group])

p.hbar_stack(age_group, y='gender', height=0.9, color=RdYlBu11, source=ColumnDataSource(males),
             legend_label=["%s males" % x for x in age_group])

p.y_range.range_padding = 0.1
p.ygrid.grid_line_color = None
p.legend.location = "top_left"
p.axis.minor_tick_line_color = None
p.outline_line_color = None

show(p)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's right there in the warning - each of your data sources has columns of different lengths.
`females` has column `F` of length 2 and column `+75` of length 1.
`males` has column `M` of length 2 and all the rest of the columns are of length 1.

I'm not sure what you want to achieve, but your data layout is definitely wrong.
A `ColumnDataSource` is a data source that represents tabular data. Each key in its `data` dict is like a column in a table, and each item at index `i` in each value of the `data` dict is like a cell in that table somewhere in the row with index `i`.

Comment: thanks, i understand the warning, I would like to know, pls, how to fix it. For instance how to change the length for F, this is a simple 2-way table with 2 columns: F, M and 11 rows labeled with age groups. How would I need to change the lenght?

Comment: I don't know what "2-way table" means. But you can just put in in a data source with, well, just as you described - two columns, `F` and `M`, and the values will represent values for the right age group. The age groups themselves don't have to be in the data source. Though you can add a third `age_group` column and store the group labels there.

Comment: yes< i guess I was hoping somebody would show me how to use DataSource as I'm unfamiliar with it.